# tried to stash using branch, how to restore without merging?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-reset

I had some temporary changes which I needed to stash so I could switch between branches without losing them.  I know this is what `git stash` is for, but I didn't want to use it (details below for the curious), so I thought, why not just commit my temporary changes to their own branch?  And that worked fine, no problem there.

The problem came after I tried to "unstash" my changes from that branch.  I had assumed I'd just do a merge, but I realized that would do a commit, which I *don't* want to do; the temporary changes are still temporary and won't be part of the next commit I'm about to prepare.

I discovered that `git merge` has a `--no-commit` option which seemed like just the ticket.  That should merge the changes in, without doing the final commit, which is just what I want.

*But*, I've just discovered, those merged changes are now in the index, meaning they'll go into my next commit anyway, unless I can get them cleanly out of the index.  Furthermore, `git status` says the merge is still in progress, and I don't want that merge I did to look like a merge; I want to pretend it never happened, although not by doing `git merge --abort`, since I do want the (partial) merge's changes to continue to be reflected in my working tree.

So my questions are, how do I get myself out of this little mess, and how do I avoid getting into this mess next time?

I *think* I might be able to get out of my mess by doing `git reset --mixed`, but my understanding of `git reset` is still imperfect, and of course `reset` is always scary, and I *really* don't want to screw up again and make things worse.  Also I'm not at all sure that `git reset` will reset the notion of the current merge-in-progress.

For next time, it looks like a better way to "merge" my stashed-on-a-branch changes might have been to do `git merge --squash`, but I'm even less sure of that, as I'd previously convinced myself (in another context) that the squash option was one I'd never want to use at all.

(So why didn't I just use `git stash` to save those uncheckedin changes in the first place?  Partly because I don't understand how `git stash` manages its stashes, and I decided I didn't want to take time to learn that right now.  Also I may want these changes on another development machine soon, so committing them to a branch and then pushing that branch was attractive.)

(Also, a side question: What state bit, stored where, records the fact that there's a merge in progress?  I'd rather use a "real" git command to reset it; I'd rather not manipulate that bit by hand, but I've been wondering where it is.)

Comment: In my opinion, it was the right decision to put your temporary changes in a commit. This makes them much more discoverable than to put them in a stash.

Comment: I agree with @j6t here: `git stash` is really just a terrible command, that probably should not even exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get out of the state (if I understand it correctly) is to use

```
git reset
```

This keeps the changes, unstages them, and removes the merge-in-progress state. (This state is identified by the presence of the file `.git/MERGE_HEAD`.)

And, yes,

```
git merge --squash --no-commit temp-branch
```

would have been the command to "unstash" the temporary changes from the temporary commit.

Comment: By the time you posted this, I had already taken a deep breath and successfully tried it, but thanks for the confirmation. :-)

Comment: In retrospect, though, I'm thinking that cherry-pick is probably a better way, in general, to "unstash" such a change, if you're "unstashing" onto a different branch, as I was doing here.  Since I merged onto a different branch, I picked up additional changes, back to the common ancestor of my temporary branch.  Fortunately that's not a serious problem — this time.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Cherry-pick is indeed the right strategy here. Note that `git reset` (with no other options and arguments) means `git reset --mixed`.

Comment: @torek Yup.  Using `--mixed` explicitly there was pure paranoia: I could see that in *other* circumstances it might not be the default, and I was exceedingly keen on [not digging my hole any deeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_holes). :-)